# Doctrine query builder wrong results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I just came across a really annoying thing. I have a queryBuilder :

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('a')
    ->addSelect('am')
    ->addSelect('m')
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->addSelect('t')
    ->leftJoin('a.articleMedias', 'am')
    ->leftJoin('am.media', 'm')
    ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('a.translations', 't')
    ->add('where', $queryBuilder->expr()->in('a.site', $ids))
;
```

When i get the results i get 192 objects.
The problem is that when i dump the sql and execute it directly into the db, i get 529 objects. But it's the same query !

Does someone know the cause for this gap between the two results ?

EDIT : found something. When i do a count query, i get 203 results but when i do a normal one and count the results i get 192 results. Does it mean doctrine has a max vars or something ?

EDIT 2 : it seems like it was an inheritance problem specific to my application. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: What is the sql query that you have done ?

Comment: It's because of the leftJoins. If you look closely at the db query result you'll see that there are lines containing `a` are present multiple times while the joined contents differ. Try adding a `GROUP BY a.id` into your native sql query (this will eliminate a lot of data but it should come down to 192 results because each entry from a will only be shown once).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found something that maybe can lead to something. When i do a sql count() query i get 203 results. But when i do a getResult() and a php count(), i get 192. It's really weird and i'm kind of lost actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely answer to this is, that you do not get 529 Objects, but 529 rows of which 192 objects are built (because of the left joins).

When putting the query directly into the db you must count the unique (or in terms of SQL: `DISTINCT` rows of your object a. Depending on your ID column change the query that you dump to `SELECT DISTINCT <you_primary_key_column>, <rest of your query>` This result should give you 192 rows which matches your 192 objects.

If not, could you please post your resulting query?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i add distinct to the query i get the same result. However if i keep only the select and the add in my querybuilder or if i group by a.id i get a closer result. The raw query returns 203 results with or without the distinct and the query builder sticks to 192. Here is the original query : https://gist.github.com/TristanPerchec/4cf6e70787bd6a7017d301a3e3ce830b